# Why does my python code not continue execution once my function "executelogin()" has been executed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am encountering a problem where my code does NOT continue execution of the rest of the program once my called function, completes execution.

Here is the function that is being called:

```
def executelogin():
    
    global initiate_game_window
    global checker
    counter = 1
    while counter < 4:
        global login_tk, game, us1_entry, us2_entry, us1_pwd_entry, us2_pwd_entry
        login_tk = Tk(screenName="Login - RollADie")
        titlelabel = Label(text="Welcome to rollaDie", font=('Open Sans', '20'))
        titlelabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)
        sublabel = Label(text="Login Below: ", font=('Open Sans', '10'))
        sublabel.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=NSEW)
        
        us1_label = Label(text="User 1:")
        us1_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us1_entry = Entry(width=10, textvariable=us1_uname)
        us1_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us1_pwd_label = Label(text="Password:")
        us1_pwd_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us1_pwd_entry = Entry(width=10, show="*", textvariable=us1_pwrd)
        us1_pwd_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us2_label = Label( text="User 2:")
        us2_label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us2_entry = Entry(width=10, textvariable=us2_uname)
        us2_entry.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us2_pwd_label = Label(text="Password:")
        us2_pwd_label.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        us2_pwd_entry = Entry(width=10, show="*", textvariable=us2_pwrd)
        us2_pwd_entry.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        def get_credentials():
            global us1_entry, us2_entry, us1_pwd_entry, us2_pwd_entry, top_login
            us1_uname = us1_entry.get()
            us1_pwrd = us1_pwd_entry.get()
            us2_uname = us2_entry.get()
            us2_pwrd = us2_pwd_entry.get()
            print(us1_uname, us1_pwrd, us2_uname, us2_pwrd)
            
            global credentials
            credentials = [us1_uname, us1_pwrd, us2_uname, us2_pwrd]
            top_login.destroy()


        global top_login
        top_login = tk.Toplevel()
        top_login.geometry('1x1+0+0')
        top_login.overrideredirect(True)
        submit_button = Button(text="Submit", command=get_credentials)
        submit_button.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        top_login.wait_window(top_login)
        
        us1_auth = False
        us2_auth = False

        if login(credentials[0], credentials[1]) == True:
            us1_auth = True
        else:
            pass

        if login(credentials[2], credentials[3]) == True:
            us2_auth = True
        else:
            pass


        if us1_auth ==  True:
            if us2_auth == True:
                print("Auth POS")
                messagebox.showinfo(message="AUTHORISED")
                login_tk.destroy()
                break
            else:
                print("User 2 AUTH NEG")
                messagebox.showinfo(message="User 2 Denied")
                counter += 1
                if counter > 3:
                    messagebox.showinfo(message="MAX ATTEMPTS")
                    quit()
                continue
        else:
            print("AUTH USER 1 NEG")
            messagebox.showinfo(message="USER 1 NOT AUTHORISED")
            counter += 1
            if counter > 3:
                    messagebox.showinfo(message="MAX ATTEMPTS")
                    quit()
            continue
    login_tk.mainloop()
```

I am not sure why this is not continuing on with the rest of the code as expected.

I'd appreciate any help.

For further reference, there is another Tk object in this file, which is initiated later down.

Thanks
şehzade Muhammad Amen Ehsan

Edit:

Below this function is the following code:

```
top = None
top_roll2 = None
faces = {'1':'\u2680', '2':'\u2681', '3':'\u2682', '4':'\u2683', '5':'\u2684', '6':'\u2685'}
root = Tk(className='RollADice', screenName='RollADice')
title = Label(text='RollADice by. Amen', font=('Open Sans', '20')).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
round_teller = Label(text='Currently: Round {0}'.format(roundnum))
round_teller.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
dicelabel = Label(root)
```

Comment: If the question is about what happens _after_ this function is called, then you would have to share that part of the code with us...

Comment: to be fair, it is quite a long chunk of code... but in short Ill add it above

Comment: But off the top of my head, this code does have some calls to `quit()`, which is one obvious way that the program could exit...

Comment: But also, remember to remove all the code that doesn't contribute to the problem: 99% of the UI setup code is irrelevant here. Run through the [mcve] exercise to make the code appropriate for posting, but _mostly_ because running through that exercise almost always lets you find the problem yourself because you're forcing yourself to check each line for "is this actually involved in my problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my 2 cents: you are creating a Tk instance within that function, and hence you have an infinite loop that wont finish until you exit from it; that is, until you exit from the login_tk mainloop.